# ReactJS: Events in .map(array) not fired

Tags: reactjs

In my `render` function I want to display a list based on an array, while displaying it works fine, it seems that whatever event I bind to it is being ignored.

```js
render: function() {
  var language = function(language) {
    return (
      <li><label>
        <input type="checkbox" value={language} onChange={this.onLanguageChange} /> 
        {language} ({_languages_total[language]})
      </label></li>
    )
  }

  return (
    <ul className="filter__list">
      <li><label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="0" onChange={this.onLanguageChange} />
        0 (2)
      </label></li>
      {this.state.languages.map(language)}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

I rendered one list item directly outside the `.map` to see if it would give any results, and this seems to be the only one that's working.

Am I just missing something obvious, or are events ignored when placed outside the `return()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the `this.onLanguageChange` doesn't refer to the right handler because `this` within the `language` function is unbound and so when it's executed points to the global object (i.e., `window`). You can do a few things to fix it:

1. Add `var self = this;` before defining `language` and refer to `self.onLanguageChange`.
2. Add `.bind(this)` after the function that you're assigning to `render`.
3. Call `.map(language, this)` to tell `map` what context to use when calling `language`. This is the simplest and cleanest solution.

If you're not familiar with JavaScript's scoping rules and how `this` works, I suggest reading up on it.

Comment: Ah, I totally overlooked that, I actually had a similar issue before, but somehow I didn't spot it in this context. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is a really useful example in the reactjs docs
http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

They basically do something like this..

```
return (
  {this.state.languages.map(function(langauge, i){
   return (
     <li><label>
        <input type="checkbox" value={language} onChange={this.onLanguageChange.bind(this, i)} /> 
        {language} ({_languages_total[language]})
      </label></li>
   )
  }, this)
 }
)
```