# Undefined function in reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Not sure what I am doing wrong here but the basics is:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

/**
 * Deal with creating a set of posts for a table.
 */
var PostRow = React.createClass({

  handleDelete: function(id){
    var postToDelete = AisisWriter.Models.Post();
    postToDelete.set({id: this});
    posttoDelete.destroy().then(this.deleted, this.fail)
    return false;
  },

  deleted: function() {
    console.log('Success - check the db for this post');
  },

  fail: function() {
    console.log('Fail');
  },

  render: function(){
    // Loop through the post objects.
    var post = this.props.posts.map(function(postObject) {
        var content = null;
        var title = null;

        // Cut off the text at anything over 140 characters
        if (postObject.content.length > 140){
           content = postObject.content.substr(0, 140) + '...';
        }else{
          content = postObject.content;
        }

        // Cut off the text at anything voer 20 characters
        if (postObject.title.length > 20){
          title = postObject.title.substr(0, 20) + '...';
        }else{
          title = postObject.title;
        }

        // Return the rows of the table.
        // React makes us have a unique key.
        return (
          <tr key={postObject.id}>
            <td>{title}</td>
            <td>{content}</td>
            <td>
              <a href={"#/post/" + postObject.id} className="btn btn-primary move-right-10px">View</a>
              <a href={"#/post/" + postObject.id + '/edit'} className="btn btn-success move-right-10px">Edit</a>
              <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleDelete(postObject.id)}>Delete</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
    });

    // Finially return the rows (note the div)
    return (
          <div>{post}</div>
      );
  }
});
```

The issue I am getting is that if I do: `this.handleDelete` life is grand, the page will load. But I need to pass in the id of this particular post id, so I tried doing what you see: `this.handleDelete(postObject.id)` how ever at that point I get: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the whole `this.handleDelete(postOject.id)`.

Have I entered call back hell? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ReactJS: Events in .map(array) not fired](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337032/reactjs-events-in-maparray-not-fired)

Comment: Yep, Ben is correct. The `this` in `this.handleDelete` isn't bound to anything, so it will refer to the global scope, window, instead of the `PostRow` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), the context of the function falls to the global scope by default, i.e. `this` refers to `window` in a browser. You can pass a context to `map` when you call it to set it to the component like your code expects:

```
// Add a `this` as the second argument to `map` to set the context to
// the current component. `this.handleDelete` will then refer to the component's
// `handleDelete` function like you are expecting.
var post = this.props.posts.map(function(postObject) {
  ...
    <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this, postObject.id)}>Delete</button>
  ...
}, this);
```

You also need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the callback function to pass `postObject.id`.

```
// The current form is a function call
this.handleDelete(postObject.id)

// `bind` returns a new function that will be passed `postObject.id` when it is
// called by React.
this.handleDelete.bind(this, postObject.id)
```